# How to make Safari reader use appropriate language for website content?

Tags: safari, internationalization, accessibility, language, voiceover

Suppose that I'm a person who uses Safari Reader to read webpages out loud, and that I'm multilingual and like to consume content in more than one language. (English and Spanish, say.) If I set my screen reading language to English in System Preferences, then Spanish content is incomprehensible, but if I set my screen reading language to Spanish, then English content is incomprehensible.

**Question:** In theory, if a webpage's HTML is tagged as having a certain language with the `lang` attribute, it should be possible to have reader mode detect the page's language and use the appropriate narration language. Is this possible to configure on my Mac? Or would I have to manually change the global Voiceover language every time I want to browse webpages in a different language?

[Web accessibility language detection with Voiceover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424963/web-accessibility-language-detection-with-voiceover) is a related Stack Overflow post about the same issue. It doesn't appear that the OP ever fully resolved their issue (or if they did, they didn't update their answer). In accordance with the upvoted answer, I've made sure that I have both English and Spanish readers installed for Voiceover (with Spanish being the default), but HTML elements marked with `lang="en"` are still pronounced as if they were in Spanish.